# Fetch particular node from xml

Tags: xml, model-view-controller

I want to fetch particular node form XML for that in model I have written below code:

```
var gp = (from Trans_Mast in r2ge.Transcription_Master where Trans_Mast.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID && Trans_Mast.Entity_Id == Job_ID select Trans_Mast).Distinct();
        foreach (var g in gp)
        {
            p.group = g.Group_xml.ToString();
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(p.group.ToString());

            var names = (xd.Descendants("Group").Where(c => c.Attribute("name").Value.Equals(GroupName))).ToList(); //xml particular data is fetch
            foreach (var item in names)
            {

            }
            data = xd.ToString();
            Transcription_Master Trans_Mast = r2ge.Transcription_Master.First(c => c.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID && c.Entity_Id == Job_ID);
            Int32 TransID = Convert.ToInt32(Trans_ID);
            r2ge.UpdateXml(TransID, data);
        }
```

from this i get XMl like

```
<Group name="Front0">
  <Room_type>Front</Room_type>
  <Dimension>Not available</Dimension>
  <Status>PENDING</Status>
  <Notes>None</Notes>
</Group>
```

Now i want to fetch only status from this xml..how to do that in foreach loop?

Comment: I have shown code..From whole Xml it fetch only matching groupname part and Now I want to fetch status node form that xml and want to change it..How to get that node @RubenSteins

Comment: You show an empty loop. I don't see any code trying to fetch the status node. Why not try to fetch it the same way you got the list of names just above the loop?

Comment: Thats what I am asking.. I can not fetch status node using above loop code @RubenSteins

Comment: yah I fetch by        foreach (var item in names)
                    {
                        item.Element("Status").Value = " ";
                    } and it working

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN-docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx), XElement (which I assume is the datatype of your 'item') also has the Descendants method. Why not use that to select the Status?

```
var status = item.Descendants("Status").FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, there's the Element method which you can use directly:

```
var status = item.Element("Status");
```